# Scoped query in Ruby model with with same name as `Enumerator#chain`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-6

A lot of models in our application have a `chain` query. Something like this:

```
scope :chain, ->(c) { where(chain: c) }
```

This works fine in Ruby 2.5, the current version we are using. But in Ruby 2.6, an `Enumerator#chain` method was added. So now, an expression like this:

```
criteria = Model.other_query.chain(@chain)
```

will call the Enumerator method (which returns an `Enumerator::Chain` object) instead of the model query.

It works fine if I use the chain method first:

```
criteria = Model.chain(@chain).other_query
```

Is there a way to get the expression to call the model query instead that does not involve renaming all the instances of our `chain` method, or rearranging all the calls?

Cheers!

Comment: What  `Model.other_query.class` return? It should return `Model::ActiveRecord::Relation` and I tried Model::ActiveRecord::Relation.instance_methods.include? :chain and returns false while ActiveRecord::Relation.instance_methods.include? :chain returns true. gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.4' ruby 2.6.3

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that  `ActiveRecord::Relation` include `Enumerable` that is included in `Enumerator` so when you call `Model.other_query.chain(@chain)` `chain` will be `Enumerator#chain`.

What you could do is something like reopening `ActiveRecord::Relation` (or prepend a `Module`), define a new `chain` method that check `self`.
I guess that if `Model` is in `ancestors` you should call `Model.chain` otherwise `super`. Something like this. I did not check it you may give it a try.

```rb
module ChainPrepend
  def chain
    if self.ancestors.inlcude? Model
      Model.chain # how make Model in scope here ?
    else
      super
    end
  end
end

class ActiveRecord::Relation
  prepend ChainPrepend
end
```